# MSVS BuildLog doesn't show dependencies defined in Properties page Linker definitions

Tags: visual-c++, dll

I am compiling a class library in MSVS2008 that depends on a couple of reference libraries.  If I look at the library's PropertiesPage.Linker.CommandLine, it correctly reflects the libraries I need:

```
/OUT:"C:\svn\Project\trunk\Service\Make\Debug\ABC_Access.dll" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO /DLL /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"Debug\ABC_Access.dll.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /ASSEMBLYDEBUG /PDB:"C:\svn\Project\trunk\Service\Make\Debug\ABC_Access.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE /FIXED:No /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT C:\svn\Project\trunk\Service\lib\Debug\MainLine_ABC.lib C:\svn\MainLine\Peripherals\nabc\lib\i86Win32VS2008\nabc1d.lib C:\svn\MainLine\Peripherals\nabc\lib\i86Win32VS2008\nabc2d.lib C:\svn\MainLine\Peripherals\nabc\lib\i86Win32VS2008\nabc3d.lib
```

However, the BuildLog shows the following and tells me one of the namespaces can't be found.  Why are my library references (specifically, nabc1d.lib, nabc2d.lib, and nabc3d.lib) not fed to the compiler and linker?

```
Creating temporary file "c:\svn\Project\trunk\Service\Make\ABC_Access\ABC_Access\Debug\RSP00000858761372.rsp" with contents
[
/Od /I "C:\svn\Mainline\Peripherals\nabc\include" /I "C:\svn\Mainline\Peripherals\nabc" /I "C:\svn\Mainline\Mainline_ABC\trunk\ABC" /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "RTI_WIN32" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /D "_WINDLL" /FD /EHa /MDd /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc90.pdb" /W3 /c /Zi /clr /TP /FU "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll" /FU "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll" /FU "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.XML.dll"
..\..\..\Service\Service\DataAccess\ABC\BasicTypes.cpp
..\..\..\Service\Service\DataAccess\ABC\BasicTypesSupport.cpp
..\..\..\Service\Service\DataAccess\ABC\BasicTypesPlugin.cpp
..\..\..\Service\Service\DataAccess\ABC\ServiceSupport.cpp
..\..\..\Service\Service\DataAccess\ABC\ServicePlugin.cpp
..\..\..\Service\Service\DataAccess\ABC\Service.cpp
]
Creating command line "cl.exe @c:\svn\Project\trunk\Service\Make\ABC_Access\ABC_Access\Debug\RSP00000858761372.rsp /nologo /errorReport:prompt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I see that I'm comparing my linker inputs to the log's reflection of compiler commands here...